# php function wont display images

Tags: php, html, image

I cannot get images to show using php function. All permissions have been granted and image location is correct but get this ..see picture

[image]

> index.php file

```
<?php
include 'inc/function.inc.php';
include 'header.php';
fetchProfile($conn);
?>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>   
</html>
```

> function.inc.php file

```
function fetchProfile($conn){
   if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
      $username = $row['uid'];
      $image = '../assets/img/profile.png';
      echo "<img src='".$image."' style='width:120px;height:120px' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
                <div class='captionN'>
                <h4>" . $username . "</h4></div>;
```

Comment: Check the location of the image that you set.

Comment: It's normal you have two path different ? the js one `assets/js/...' and the image `../assets/img...`. Be carreful, your script tag should be on the body element, not outside :)

Comment: they are two different files `index.php` & `function.inc.php` and the locations/paths are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved -> 
When operating from functions in a different file, the path will remain the location from the `index.php` and not from the `function.inc.php's` location.

> index.php file

```
<?php
include 'inc/function.inc.php';
include 'header.php';
fetchProfile($conn);
?>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>   
</html>
```

> function.inc.php file

```
function fetchProfile($conn){
   if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
      $username = $row['uid'];
      $image = 'assets/img/profile.png';
      echo "<img src='".$image."' style='width:120px;height:120px' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
                <div class='captionN'>
                <h4>" . $username . "</h4></div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the image is `../assets/img/profile.png`, **if** the file index.php is at the root of your site it is normal that the image doesn't appear because you are trying to fetch a file that is outside your site.

The problem could be that the folder assets is outside of your site or that your path is not correct.